# Jacobian of linear transformation equal to linear transformation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, jacobian

I am working on the following proof:

---

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and let $f: V \longrightarrow W$ be linear. Proof that $Df(x) = f$.

---

Now, I have seen some proofs on the internet that use the fact, that for each linear function $f$ there exists a matrix $A$ such that forall $x \in V \, \exists \, y \in W$ so that

$$y = A \cdot x$$

or componentwise

$$y_i = A_{ij} \, x_j$$

Therefore, one has

$$ \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_k} = A_{ij} \, \delta_{jk} = A_{ik} $$

Which would prove the identity $Df(x) = f$. Now, my problem with this proof is, that the derivatives

$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_k}$$

should be understood as the derivatives of $y_i$ with respect to the **coordinates** $x_k$. The equation $y = A \cdot x$ however takes a **vector** $x \in V$ and maps it onto a vector $y \in W$. So, calling the vector $x$ is just a name for an object in $V$, which I could also have called $v \in V$. Therefore the derivatives

$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k}$$

are actually

$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k}$$

and therefore not (necessarily) $\delta_{ik}$. What do I miss here? Am I misconceptioning something here?

---

---

**EDIT 1**

With *EXODD*'s help I figured out the proof as follows (see comments).

$$\partial_k f_i(v) = f_i(e_k) = \tilde{e}_i \cdot f(e_k)$$

where $e_i$ are a basis of $V$ and $\tilde{e}_i$ are a basis of $W$. Now, there exists a transformation matrix $A$ such that

$$\tilde{e}_i \cdot f(e_k) = A_{ik}$$

which in turn are the components of the transformation matrix for the linear map $f$. Thank you for your help *EXODD*.

${}$

However, I am again stuck with the follow-up-question. It is

**Proposition**: Let $U, V, W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and let $g : U \times V \longrightarrow W$ be bilinear. Show that for $(u_1,v_1) \in U \times V$ and $(u_2, v_2) \in U \times V$ it holds that

$$\Big( D \, g(u_1,v_1) \Big) (u_2, v_2) = g(u_1,v_2) + g(u_2,v_1)$$.

*Proof*: By calculating the partial derivative, I came up with

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f_i(u_1,v_1) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \Big( f_i (u_1 + he_j, v_1 + he_j) - f_i(u_1, v_1) \Big) \\
&{} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \Big( hf_i(u_1, e_j) + hf_i(e_j,v_1) + h^2f_i(e_j,e_j) \Big) \\
&{} \\
&= f_i(u_1, e_j) + f_i(e_j,v_1)
\end{align*}

But again, I am unable to proceed from here.

Comment: If it makes you feel safer, you could actually use the definition of partial derivative, as a limit of the rate $\partial f_j/\partial x_i (v) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (f_j(v + \epsilon e_i) - f_j(v))/\epsilon$, where $e_i$ is the canonical basis vector with a $1$ on the $i$-th position.

Comment: Im stuck with the last part here. What I have is ... $$\partial_k f_i(v) = \lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} \tfrac{1}{h} \Big( f_i( v + he_k ) - f_i(v) \Big) = \lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} \tfrac{1}{h} \Big( f_i(v) + hf_i(e_k) - f_i(v) \Big) = \lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} f_i(e_k) = f_i(e_k)$$ But how do I proceed further?

Comment: Now you know that $f(v) = Av$, and $f_i(v) = e_i^t f(v)$, so $f_i(e_k) = e_i^tAe_k = A_{i,k}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I updated my question to include (a sketch of) your proof. I also added a new question. I probably should have opened a new thread - however, I thought this question belonged here since it is a follow-up of the previous question. If you would find some time to look at it and tell me your thoughts, I would appreciate it sincerely.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't even bring in partial derivatives to prove these questions. THe concept of partial derivatives are not the primary focus. THese follow almost immediately from the definitions (especially the one about linearity).

Comment: Hm, I can't follow. The problem is to prove an identity including the Jacobian, which in turn includes partial derivatives. I don't see how I should proceed only using linearity.

Comment: I suggest you to write down the definitions of what you are using, and keep in mind that $g$ is bilinear, and the Jacobian is linear

Comment: Hey @Octavius. How is it going? Did you manage to do the exercises without using partial derivatives? Or are you really sure you want to do it using partial derivatives?